# How to make a tab (i.e. Home, About, Contact) clickable in HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to make my menu button clickable so that it navigates to the desired section or another page with another content. For example in my website I have a menu "About me". I want that as soon as an user clicks on it should be able to see the paragraph about "ABOUT ME" which I stored in my HTML file.

I have another problem and that is when I make the window size smaller the paragraph text moves into unwanted position (in my case below menu area). Otherwise, in full sized window it's fine.

I left my javascript class empty because I haven't needed any .js functinality yet.

My code:

main.html:

```
    <!--
All the html code will go in this file. This is the main core file of any website.
Some php code may be included if necessary.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<html lang="en">
<html charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome to Fatah's world!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main_design.css"/>



<!--<img src="bricks.JPG" alt="blue bricks" width="300" height="1000">-->
<style type="text/css">
<!--right now nothing to do here-->
</style>
</head>

<body>


<h1 id="style_header">Welcome to my green world!</h1></div>


<div id="menu_area" >


<div id="home">HOME</div><br /><br /><br /> 
<div id="about_me">ABOUT ME</div><br /><br /> <br />
<div id="gallery">GALLERY</div><br /><br /> <br />
<div id="contact_me">CONTACT ME</div><br /><br /> <br />
<div id="my_diary">MY DIARY</div><br /><br /> <br />
<div id="blog">BLOG</div><br /><br /> <br />


</div>


<!-- I want to call the home.html class here so that the paragraph is shown in my homepage under the home menu.-->
<p id="paragraph_home"><b>
Thank you for spending your time to visit my website. 
My name is Jabir Al Fatah. I live in Sweden. I have 
a lot of interest in web developing and 3d graphics 
designing. I am a travel addicted guy. I love to travel and 
have experience about diversity among life and nature.
I am passionate. I don't do everything just becuase I 
am obliged to do,rather I like to take risk to be done 
with something just because I like.I haven't have a 
wonderful childhood in my life. But I admit it that my 
parents were surprisingly aware of my future and even 
every singlestep in my life. Their love and affection 
fulfilled all of my demand.Well, I just admired them a 
little. There are tons of others stuff I can say. 
However, in my life, changes happen very fast. 
</b></p>

<p id="paragraph_aboutme">This paragraph should appear while clicking on "About me". Beisides,
it's not accurately placed in the window. I need to fix that
.Another problem is that this paragraph moves under the menu area by 
pushing it up when I make the window size smaller. </p>


<div id="footer">Developed by Jabir Al Fatah</div>

</body>
</html>
```

main_design.css:

```
    /*
All the css properties will go in this file. CSS properties design the site to look it prettier.
*/
#style_header {
    background-color:blue;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    margin:-8px;
    border:4px solid red;
}

#paragraph_home{ 
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    width:300px;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family:verdana;
    color:blue;
    size:20px;
    margin:9px;
}
#paragraph_aboutme {
text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    font-family:verdana;
    color:blue;
    size:20px;
    margin:9px;
    }

#menu_area {
    border:4px solid red;
    margin:-8px;
    background-color:#FFD700;
    padding-top:30px;
    margin-top:4px;
    height:600px;
    width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
body {
    background-image:url(green.JPG);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#footer {
    background-color:gray;
    margin:-8px;
    margin-top:6px;
    border:2px solid green;
    text-align:center;
    /*margin-bottom:-20px;*/
    width:99.6%;
    position:absolute;



}
#home {
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
    text-align:left;
}
#about_me {
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
    text-align:left;
}
#gallery {
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
    text-align:left;
}
#contact_me {
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
    text-align:left;
}
#my_diary {
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
    text-align:left;
}
#blog {
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
    text-align:left;
}
```

main_interaction.js:

```
    /*
All the java script code will go in this file. This class will add all the interaction and behaviour functionality for
the website.
*/
```

Comment: what <a> does? and where to put it?

Comment: <a> is called the anchor tag. [Read more...](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Comment: Do you want multiple tabs in same page?

Comment: no. I just want to make my tabs clickable (for example clicking on "About Me" will show the paragraph related about me). but the paragraph shouldn't be readily seen while loading a page by the user. It can only be seen once the user click on "About Me". You know how all the website works in current world. For example if you click the contact tab it will show the contact page. ok what happens if you click on "News" tab on this website: http://www.alex-hepburn.com/                       the same functionality/effect i want.

Comment: Can you please try this http://jsfiddle.net/F9L3v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's basically what you want.
Do note that I used [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) as a CSS framework, which makes it alot easier to create lay-outs like yours. I took the liberty to build your lay-out from the ground up, without any special colors.

**DEMO: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tPC98/2/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="header" class="col-xs-12">
         <h1>Welcome to my green world!</h1>

        <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <ul>
            <li id="home">HOME</li>
            <li id="gallery">GALLERY</li>
            <li id="about">ABOUT ME</li>
            <li id="contact">CONTACT ME</li>
            <li id="diary">MY DIARY</li>
            <li id="blog">BLOG</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 home">
        <p>Thank you for spending your time to visit my website. My name is Jabir Al Fatah. I live in Sweden. I have a lot of interest in web developing and 3d graphics designing. I am a travel addicted guy. I love to travel and have experience about diversity among life and nature. I am passionate. I don't do everything just becuase I am obliged to do,rather I like to take risk to be done with something just because I like.I haven't have a wonderful childhood in my life. But I admit it that my parents were surprisingly aware of my future and even every singlestep in my life. Their love and affection fulfilled all of my demand.Well, I just admired them a little. There are tons of others stuff I can say. However, in my life, changes happen very fast.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 gallery hidden">
        <p>This is the gallery.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 about hidden">
        <p>This paragraph should appear while clicking on "About me". Beisides, it's not accurately placed in the window. I need to fix that .Another problem is that this paragraph moves under the menu area by pushing it up when I make the window size smaller.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 contact hidden">
        <p>Contact me here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 diary hidden">
        <p>My diary will be here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 blog hidden">
        <p>Blog posts appear here.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="col-xs-12">
        Developed by Jabir Al Fatah</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
    margin: 0;
}
#header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
.col-xs-9 {
    font-family:'Verdana';
    font-size: 13pt;
}
.col-xs-3 {
    border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
    line-height: 40pt;
    font-family:'Tahoma';
    font-size: 15pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.col-xs-3 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("li").on('click', function () {
    $(".col-xs-9").addClass("hidden");
    $("." + $(this).attr("id")).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

If you insist on having about the same colors you used back, then use this link: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tPC98/1/)

Comment: how does the bootstrap thigs work? i installed that in my computer. do i need to save all my files inside bootstrap.i see that u used jquery. that means i have to run apache, right? otherwise if i just copy paste ur code into my file, it doesn't work. it just have plain text/paragraph, but no color, border or functionality.

Comment: ur suggestion works fine now. but why do we need to name a class like this: col-xs-8? or col-xs-16? what specific task they do? is there any alternative of them?

Comment: Well once you've got Bootstrap working (which you seem to have), the `col-xs-8` and `col-xs-12` defines how much space a column can occupy on your page. This is how it's defined in Bootstrap. The syntax looks like this: `col-[pageWidth]-[columnSpan]`, with `pageWidth` being the size of the browser (eXtra Small, SMall, MeDium and LarGe), and `columnSpan` being the amount of columns (with a total of 12) the chosen element should occupy. For more information, see here: [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so here are a few techniques that could work:

if you want that paragraph to show up ONLY when they are in that section of the website (like home, about, etc), just put it in a div, and name the div what you want that paragraph to be called, example

```
<div id="about">
This is the about paragraph!
</div>
```

then go to your CSS and add this:

```
    #about {
display: none;
}
```

what this will do is make it so that the web page doesn't render it at all.

Ok so next you need to make your about link button (this technically isn't a link though, your just rendering and hiding a div).  Once you find your button add this code somewhere in the tag

```
onclick="showabout()"
```

this will make it so that when they click this button it will run this showabout() function
in your javascript:

```
    function showabout() {
//THIS CODE HIDES ALL OF THE OTHER DIVS \/ \/ \/
document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("Gallery").style.dispaly = "none";
//FOR EACH PARAGRAPH ADD ONE OF THE ABOVE LINES OF CODE AND SIMPLY CHANGE THE ID, LIKE HOME, OR GALLERY, ETC

//THIS LINE OF CODE BELOW THEN SHOWS THE PARAGRAPH \/ \/ \/
document.getElementById("about").style.display = "block";
}
```

so then just list your paragraphs in your HTML like so:

```
<div id="home">This is the Home paragraph!</div>
<div id="about">This is the About paragraph!</div>
<div id="gallery">This is the Gallery paragraph!</div>
(Etc)
```

and that's it!  Your code will swap out the paragraphs for you!

If you don't want to do it that way you could simply just make several different pages and then make hyperlinks between them... Which honestly I don't understand why you don't just want to do it that way, its normally a lot easier and looks just as good.

If you don't want to do it that way you could put an IFrame in your website and just have them as separate pages but then show the iFrame below, but Iframes are kinda hated by search engines so its going to really hurt you if you want your page high on the search results....

If you still don't want to do it that way don't fear, there is an actual language that is programmed to do what you want to do, its called [Meteor.js](http://meteor.com).  You would also have to use iron-router though, and that means you are going to also need to install meteorite.

Concerning your paragraph that keeps moving when you change your screen size.  I faced this problem a lot before I knew the simple answer, which is:

1) Use [Floating](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) (a css property to push the div or element as far to one horizontal direction as possible)

2) Don't use px in css, use %!  This way your paragraphs change when your screen size changes.  (% or percent is a measurement based of the screen size, so 20% is 20% of the screen size)

3) If you don't want it to move at all, use [CSS Position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)!

Best of luck!!!