# Why on('click', function ()) isn't working in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html

I have a very simple website with some menu tabs (i.e. Home, About Me etc.) and few paragraphs. I added click function inside my .JS file so that the clicking on tab can navigate to the desired paragraph (or page). But it's not working.

I should refernce to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079623/how-to-make-a-tab-i-e-home-about-contact-clickable-in-html/25080751#25080751) as I posted back.

[NOTE: I have apache running in my computer and xwamp is installed. I have jquery source added into my file and they are accurately saved in correct path or file. Besides I have Bootstrap installed, though I didn't necessarily need to set path for any file to it.]

My code:

main.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<html lang="en">
<html charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome to Fatah's world!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main_design.css"/>

<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/main_interaction.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div id="header" class="col-xs-12">
         <h1>Welcome to my green world!</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <ul>
            <li id="home">HOME</li>
            <li id="gallery">GALLERY</li>
            <li id="about">ABOUT ME</li>
            <li id="contact">CONTACT ME</li>
            <li id="diary">MY DIARY</li>
            <li id="blog">BLOG</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 home">
        <p>Thank you for spending your time to visit my website. My name is Jabir Al Fatah. I live in Sweden. I have a lot of interest in web developing and 3d graphics designing. I am a travel addicted guy. I love to travel and have experience about diversity among life and nature. I am passionate. I don't do everything just becuase I am obliged to do,rather I like to take risk to be done with something just because I like.I haven't have a wonderful childhood in my life. But I admit it that my parents were surprisingly aware of my future and even every singlestep in my life. Their love and affection fulfilled all of my demand.Well, I just admired them a little. There are tons of others stuff I can say. However, in my life, changes happen very fast.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 gallery hidden">
        <p>This is the gallery.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 about hidden">
        <p>This paragraph should appear while clicking on "About me". Beisides, it's not accurately placed in the window. I need to fix that .Another problem is that this paragraph moves under the menu area by pushing it up when I make the window size smaller.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 contact hidden">
        <p>Contact me here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 diary hidden">
        <p>My diary will be here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 blog hidden">
        <p>Blog posts appear here.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="col-xs-12">Developed by Jabir Al Fatah</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

.JS:

```
   $("li").on('click', function () {
    $(".col-xs-8").addClass("hidden");
    $("." + $(this).attr("id")).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

.CSS:

```
    @import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
.row {
    margin: 0;
}
#header {
    background-color: mediumturquoise;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 4px solid crimson;
}
.col-xs-8 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Verdana';
    color: mediumblue;
    font-size: 13pt;
}
.col-xs-4{
    border: 4px solid crimson;
    background-color: yellow;
    line-height: 40pt;
    font-family:'Tahoma';
    font-size: 15pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.col-xs-4 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#footer {
    background-color: gray;
    border: 2px solid green;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting (if any) in the console? Should `$("." + $(this).attr("id"))` be `$("#" + $(this).attr("id"))`? Is there a way you can reduce the code you've posted to contain a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/)?

Comment: Probably you committed a typo here: `$("." + $(this).attr("id")).removeClass("hidden");` it should be `$("#" +...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're including (and thus executing) the JavaScript before the elements exist on the page.  HTML/JavaScript is processed in the order in which is exists in the DOM.  So when this runs:

```
$("li")
```

the parser is only at the top of the HTML body and hasn't loaded any `li` elements into the DOM yet.  Thus, that selector doesn't find anything.

Either put the JavaScript at the end of the DOM or wrap it in a document ready handler:

```
$(function () {
    $("li").on('click', function () {
        // etc.
    });
});
```

(or both)

Comment: alright, works well now.

Answer (score 1):

`on` not support from `jquery 1.9`, try `live`

```
$("li").live("click",function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and was wondering if replacing

```
$("li").on('click', function () {
```

with

```
$("li").click(function() {
```

would solve the issue. I've used jquery for a while but have never used ".on" but my onclicks work fine. Hope this helps!